# React, what's the prefered way of updating state

Tags: reactjs, immutability

```
state = {
  blog: {
    name: 'abc',
    score: 5
  }
}


var { blog } = this.state
```

// you want to do blog.score = 5

```
1. blog = _.merge({}, blog, {
  score: 3
})


2. blog = {
    ...blog,
    score: 5
   }

3. blog = update(blog, {
     $set: {
       score: 5
     }
   }

this.setState({blog})
```

I don't know if there are other ways, but would there be any preference over these?

what about

```
state = {
  site: { 
    blog: {
      name: 'abc',
      score: 5
    }
  }
}


site = _.merge({}, site, {
  blog: {
    score: 5
  }
})


site = update(site, {
  blog: {
    $set: {
      score: 5
    }
  })


this.setState({site})
```

Answer (score 1):

[reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) already provides utility to merge previous state with new one.

```
let newState = React.addons.update(this.state, {
  blog: {
    score: { $set: 5}
  }
});
this.setState(newState);
```

[More details about this addon](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

`_.merge` is a plausible solution, but the recommended way would be to use https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper since `react-addons-update` has been deemed a legacy add-on.